# How would I ensure data congruity for a JSON column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

We decided to store some 'meta data' per record for one of our entities (Let's call this entity Order). Let's say that this Order contains other entities named 'Item'. One piece of meta data we store in JSON is something akin to 'Sent Items', which is a list of IDs of items that have already been sent.

Let's say we have an order for which no items have been sent. Now let's say two people each decide to send a different item at the exact same time. I would assume person 1's JSON file will contain the ID for his item, person 2's JSON file will contain the ID for his item, and the database will contain whatever piece of JSON data that gets written last (containing only 1 ID).

Is there any way to avoid this sort of situation? Or is this an unavoidable downside to storing this type of data in a JSON column?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a classic concurrency issue, not particular to json. Unless you result to locking, last one in wins. Consider using optimistic concurrency (e.g. with rowversion) and retry when a conflict is detected.

Comment: if json_modify() then each person’s (different) items can be inserted into the column (the second person will be blocked until the first finishes the modification/transaction)